# Why can't I access the bit.ly boomarklet?

Tags: javascript, dom, bookmarklet, web-inspector

I beautified their code and it looks like this:

```
(function() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.setAttribute("id", "bitmark_js");
    s.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    s.setAttribute("src", "//path_to_your_file.js");
    (top.document.body || top.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]).appendChild(s);
})();
```

When I could not find it in using the web inspector, I tried to pull it from the DOM by ID while inside the console using

```
document.getElementById('bitmark_js');
```

I can clearly see the bookmarklet being diplayed but can't access it.  Why not?

Comment: Did you execute the bookmarklet first?

Comment: And if you click on it to inspect the element, you see the id?

Comment: Go into the network tab and look at the script, it will be there.

Comment: It creates an iframe that takes up the entire page.